# Faithfulness of parabolic induction

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

I've only recently begun to study the representation theory of $p$-adic groups, so the following question might be quite silly.

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field of residue characteristic $p$, $\mathbb{G}$ a reductive group over $F$ and $G=\mathbb{G}(F)$ its group of $F$-rational points. When considering the category $\text{Rep}_R(G)$ of smooth $RG$-modules, I can't quite get a hold of the ubiquitous necessity of requiring $p$ to be invertible in $R$: this seems to be a universal assumption made on $R$ (often I've seen $R=\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ or $R=\mathbb{F}_\ell$ where $\ell$ is a prime different to $p$). Recently, I've come across the statement that, whenever $P = U \rtimes L$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$, together with a Levi decomposition, the parabolic induction functor $$
I_P : \text{Rep}_{\mathbb{F}_\ell}(L) \longrightarrow \text{Rep}_{\mathbb{F}_\ell}(G)
$$ is faithful so long as $\ell \neq p$, and for some reason I get the feeling that this should be a very easy statement to prove which should so-to-speak obviously go wrong if $\ell = p$, but I've struggled to find either an argument or a counterexample.

To illustrate my thoughts, I figured if $L = \mathbb{Q}_p^\times \times \mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ is the subgroup of diagonal matrices in $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ fitted into the parabolic subgroup given by upper triangular matrices, then since $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times \cong \langle p \rangle \times \mathbb{F}_p^\times \times (1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{F}_p^\times \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ we can let $L$ (ignoring the first two factors) act on $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\oplus 2}$ almost like a unipotent group, which is something I suppose one should often avoid (?). Nonetheless, I can't seem to understand how parabolic induction, for instance, in this case should be ill-behaved...

Thank you so much for the help; any piece of advice is hugely appreciated.

UPDATE: so I asked a few friends and yeah, parabolic induction is an additive, exact functor which reflects the zero object: factoring an arbitrary morphism of rep's $X\to Y$ as a surjection composed with an injection and then applying $I_P$ shows (by the previous three properties I stated) that $f$ can't map to zero if it isn't zero itself :p In conclusion, parabolic induction is always faithful.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what the question is.  Does your update answer it?  If so, then it would probably be appropriate to give your update as an answer, and to accept that answer.  This is reasonable, since the question has been otherwise unanswered for two weeks.